# Previous Date get selected of min date react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-datepicker

I have used minDate={moment(new Date('1-01-1970'))}
but I am able to select 31/12/1969.
Set any min date in react date picker able to select the previous date.
I am using react-datepicker 
npm link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Any solution.

```
<DatePicker
    ref="drvDatePicker"
    utcOffset={utcOffset}
    className="date-picker"
    popperClassName="drv-datepicker-popper"
    onChange={input ? value => input.onChange(value) : undefined}
    onClickOutside={this.onClickOutside}
    minDate={moment(new Date('1-01-1970'))}
/>
```

Comment: just remove `moment()`, `new Date('1-01-1970')`.

Comment: Have you tried setting min date +1 ? Not an elegant solution but it should work

Comment: `1-01-1970` is an invalid string for the `Date` constructor. Try e.g. `2-01-1970` to see that's the case. You want `YYYY-MM-DD`, e.g. `1970-01-02`. The datepicker also expects a `Date` object, not a moment.

Comment: Date object doesn't work with my version of datepicker I am using 1.6 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using 1.6 version and not possible to upgrade the version
Setting min date +1 day.

```
    <DatePicker
        ref="drvDatePicker"
        utcOffset={utcOffset}
        className="date-picker"
        popperClassName="drv-datepicker-popper"
        onChange={input ? value => input.onChange(value) : undefined}
        onClickOutside={this.onClickOutside}
        minDate={moment(new Date('02-01-1970'))}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this part](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker#momentjs) of the description, you don't need `moment` anymore:

> Up until version 1.8.0, this package was using Moment.js. Starting v2.0.0, we switched to using native Date objects to reduce the size of the package.

Comment: I cannot upgrade the version due to hard dependencies I am using 1.6 version

Comment: That information would have been nice to begin with.
Try `moment('1-01-1970', 'D-MM-YYYY')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker
    ref="drvDatePicker"
    utcOffset={utcOffset}
    className="date-picker"
    popperClassName="drv-datepicker-popper"
    onChange={input ? value => input.onChange(value) : undefined}
    onClickOutside={this.onClickOutside}
    minDate={new Date('1-01-1970')}
/>
```